# unique ptr initialisation assertion failure

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

This causes my program to have an assertion failure:

```
int a = 5;
std::unique_ptr<int>intptr(&a);
```

The error

> File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp
>
> Line: 32
>
> Expression : _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead > nBlockUse)

It works well when I initialise it using "new" or " = make_unique (..)" but I'm curious to know why I can't initialise it by giving the adress of an existing variable.

Comment: You cannot allocate or deallocate memory from the stack. Since `a` was declared on the stack, you cannot delete it, which is what your `unique_ptr` tries to do when it falls out of scope.

Comment: Out of interest, what were you trying to achieve here?

Comment: doctorlove -> Nothing, I am just trying things for learning purposes

Comment: for learning purposes, the less you use the heap in C++ the better .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable a is on the stack, if you bind it to a unique_ptr, when the unique_ptr will go out of scope, it will call delete on a variable that can not be deleted.

basically you can't get ownership of an automatic storage variable, only a dynamic one.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize. Error is in destruction of `unique_ptr`, since by default it `delete` owner pointer. You should create with `new`, or use customer deleter.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* initialize the `unique_ptr` to an automatic variable by using a custom deleter like this:

```
auto noop = [](int*){};
std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(noop)>intptr(&a, noop);
```

Just remember not to let the pointer escape the scope where the automatic variable lives.

But it probably doesn't make any sense to use `unique_ptr` here at all, so you might want to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use address only if you have some *weird* custom deleter that does nothing for actual destroying.

```
struct D{

    void operator()(int* p) const {
        std::cout << "Deleter \n";
        //... no actual delete
    }
};  

int a =5;    
std::unique_ptr<int,D> intptr (&a);
```